# Raster with distances to points along road system?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster, rgdal

I have a shapefile of roads/avenues in a city, and another shapefile with markets. I need to produce a raster where each pixel has the distance to the nearest market along the road system. Is there any R package that does that?

[image: city map]

The image above exemplifies a part of the road system, with two markets (green triangles). The idea is to make data to generate a ["food desert"](https://www.ers.usda.gov/amber-waves/2011/december/data-feature-mapping-food-deserts-in-the-us/) map in the city level [(example at national level)](https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/food-access-research-atlas/go-to-the-atlas/).

EDIT

[Roads/Avenues shapefile](http://bhmap.pbh.gov.br/v2/api/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ide_bhgeo:HIERARQUIZACAO_VIARIA&srsName=EPSG:31983&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP) (4.1 MB zipped file)

[Markets shapefile](http://bhmap.pbh.gov.br/v2/api/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ide_bhgeo:CENTRO_INCLUSAO_DIGITAL&srsName=EPSG:31983&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP) (21.5 kB zipped file. The [real shapefile](http://bhmap.pbh.gov.br/v2/api/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ide_bhgeo:ATIVIDADE_ECONOMICA&srsName=EPSG:31983&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP) is too big - 62.4 MB - so I'm using another data also consisting of points)

Comment: The answer is yes. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example that includes simple example data generated by code?

Comment: @RobertHijmans It's easier to provide the links for the original shapefiles (4.1 MB and 21.5 kB zipped files). Is there any problem?